# Is the time complexity of this code O(n^2)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

The problem finds two items in the array that add up to target value. 
It returns an array w/ the index of the correct values.

I think the time complexity is n^2 because the while loop runs through array once so n time. And in the worst case, it has to repeat this n times. So n*n running time.

Even though the number of elements it has to iterate through decreases each time, we drop the constants when calc. time complexity.

Is this analysis correct?
Any recommendations for bringing it down to n?

```
def twoSum(nums, target):

    indx = []
    size = len(nums)

    if (size < 2):
        return indx

    x = 0
    y = size - 1

    while(x < y):

        if( (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target):
            indx[0] = x
            indx[1] = y
            break
        elif ( (y - 1) == x):
            x = x + 1
            y = size - 1
        else:
            y = y -1

    return indx
```

Comment: I think the time complexity is right. I am not sure you can bring this to O(n)

Comment: @Broman: No, it's definitely O(n^2). The loop goes over all pairs of elements. (Also it tries to assign to nonexistent list indices, so it's not actually going to return the right thing.)

Comment: @user2357112 But the list decreases by one each time, making it O(n log n), right?

Comment: @Broman: No. n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+2+1=n\*(n+1)/2.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `O(n)`, this is a google interview question that they have a video on YouTube for I believe. Or at least they had a very similar problem:

```
def twoSum(nums, target):
    values = dict()
    for index, n in enumerate(nums):
        if target - n in values:
            return values[target - n], index
        else:
            values[n] = index


print(twoSum([4, 5, 2, 1, 3], 4)) # (3, 4)
```

**- Edit -**
Per the comments below, this solution technically still has a worst case of `O(n^2)` do to hash collisions.  For most cases you should get close to `O(n)` but if you are working with large numbers (negative or positive) you will see an increase in collisions which will result `n * log(n)` to `n^2` time (especially if the test set given to you tries to target hash collisions).

Comment: This is only usual-case O(n), though. It degrades to O(n^2) in the face of a pretty easy hash collision attack.

Comment: Which is no longer easy thanks to hash randomisation

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: There's no hash randomization for ints.

Comment: I think that the problem is still o(n^2) in the worst case.

Comment: (And in case anyone's thinking "ints hash to themselves so they can't collide", first, large enough ints don't hash to themselves (and also -1 hashes to -2 but that has little effect here), and second, even if element magnitude is restricted, you can still go for cell-level collisions where the probe sequence for new elements keeps hitting filled table cells even though the hashes are distinct. It just makes the math more complicated.)

Comment: @user2357112 oops :D you got me :P

Comment: @user2357112 Good point.  Though to actually get `O(n^2)` is extremely difficult (the input would have to basically be a hash collision attack as you say). This solution is typically fast but does suffer from hash collisions. Thank you, I added an amendment to my answer.